# Exception in CoinChangeProblem code

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception, coin-change

import java.io.*;

```
public class CoinChangeProblem {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int[] arr;
    arr = new int[]{1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 500, 1000};
    int[] arr2;
    arr2 = new int[]{-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1};
    int max_coin = 0, due, i = 0, j = 0;
    BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.print("\n\n\tEnter the amount of currency due");
    due = Integer.parseInt(stdin.readLine());
    while (due != 0) {
        for (j = 0; due > arr[j] && j < 9; )
            max_coin = arr[j++];
        j = 0;
        arr2[i] = max_coin;
        due = due - max_coin;
        i += 1;
    }
    i = 0;
    for (int k = 0; arr2[k] != -1; k++) {
        System.out.print(" " + arr2[k]);
    }
}
}
```

The compiler is throwing ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at line 9 and 23.If you have got a solution please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last iteration of your for loop makes `arr2[i] = max_coin` access `arr2[9]` but your array's last index is 8.

Comment: Yeah I added a condition to restraint I up to 8 index and it is working fine,although logic has a hole itself,anyways thank you for ur kind help ☺

Answer (score 0):

Change your loop as

```
for(j=0; j<9 && due>arr[j];)
    max_coin=arr[j++];
```

Java works with short circuiting, therefore when you check if j is smaller than 9 first, then it will be false and loop ends.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response ,I didn't know about this concept until now ☺

Answer (score 0):

This program gets an input variable from standard input which is stored in 'due' local variable. It just works when the 'due' input is <= 7. If the input value is greater than 7 this exception raises:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9
>   at CoinChangeProblem.main(CoinChangeProblem.java:23)

Pay attention the '9' is not the line number, it indicates given index which is more than the max size of your array. The size of 'attr2' array is 9 and it supports [0-8] indexes. So when 'i' variable reaches to number 9, then 'arr2[i]' expressions causes the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Yeah I fixed that statement and it is working now.Thankyou for your help ☺

Comment: @nishant you are welcome, if it helped you can select the answer as  solution or give it a plus.